# Which blacklist.conf file version should I use to block the loading of the nouveau module?

Tags: kernel, modules

I want to block the loading of the *nouveau* kernel module but in my /usr/lib/modprobe.d directory I have 2 blacklist.conf files:

```
blacklist_linux-raspi_5.15.0-1023-raspi.conf

blacklist_linux-raspi_5.15.0-1024-raspi.conf
```

It seems these 2 conf files correspond to different linux-raspi kernel versions.

My current linux-raspi kernel version is 5.15.0-1024-raspi

So to prevent the automatic loading of the module *nouveau*, I will add the line

```
blacklist nouveau
```

In which blacklist.conf files should I add the line? Does it matter?

Comment: your question is about Linux, not about Raspberry Pi ... it belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: What OS? What have you done before? Under normal conditions you will not have multiple kernels.

Comment: I use Linux RasPi 5.15.0-1024-raspi.

Comment: That is a kernel. What **OS**? NOTE edit your Question DO NOT put detail in coments

Comment: It doesn't matter. The Linux kernel will read all *.conf files in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be a good idea to find out *why* the nouveau module is being loaded, since it cannot be used for anything.  Anyway:

> It seems these 2 conf files correspond to different linux-raspi kernel versions.

Nope.  From `man modprobe.d`:

> All files underneath the /etc/modprobe.d directory which end with the .conf extension specify those options as required.

Ie., all the files in that directory ending in `.conf` will be processed.  So just add your own `whatever.conf` and:

```
blacklist nouveau
```